# How to check for the current user's password?

Tags: apex, passwords

Is it possible to check for the current user's password in a programmatic fashion with Apex?

My current use case is that management wants the current user to authorize a certain procedure, and to authenticate that they need to provide their password.

Comment: Nice Q&A, but this is kind of an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) if you don't say why you needed this. For example, if you're just trying to log in, `Site.login()` might be more appropriate. It should be incredibly rare to need to actually check a user's password.

Comment: Not in a community. Added the snippet with the use case (even though I agree its an unusual thing to ask for).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to check the user's password with Apex through the `UserManagement` class:

```
Auth.VerificationResult res = UserManagement.verifyVerificationMethod(
    null,
    'the actual password',
    Auth.VerificationMethod.PASSWORD
);
System.debug(res);
```

The output is a Auth.VerificationResult object in which you can check the message and the success:

```
16:50:55:055 USER_DEBUG [6]|DEBUG|VerificationResult:[message=FailedInvalidPassword, redirect=null, success=false]
```

If the success attribute returns `true`,  then the password matches.

Comment: An alternative implementation to consider here is to force the user to prove their identity through high assurance session functionality and the [generateVerificationUrl](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Auth_SessionManagement.htm#apex_Auth_SessionManagement_generateVerificationUrl) method.